# caliper leaking...

Tags: ford, brakes, taurus

I drive a 2008 Ford Taurus X. In June, I had the rear rotors and pads replaced. They also had to replace the right rear caliper. Last week (less than 2,000 miles later) the left rear caliper started leaking. Took the car back to the Ford service center and they now have to replace the left rear caliper.

2 questions: 
1. Could this problem really just come up in the past 6 weeks? (No accidents or emergency stops since the work done in June.) I feel like they should have noticed this ...
2. Is it reasonable for me to have to pay AGAIN for brake fluid system flush?

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: The car, and the caliper, are seven years old. Maybe it wasn't leaking six weeks ago but its been in service for much longer than that. If they are replacing the caliper the flush should be part of the job IMO.If you are concerned you should see a local mechanic for a second opinion. Good luck

Comment: It sounds as though the dealership was actually trying to save you money by only doing the work which was needed at the time. They do not have a crystal ball which tells them when a part is going to fail. Besides, it isn't a "flush" they'd be doing, but bleeding the brakes ... which in brake parlance could be considered a flush, I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the question you are asking is "could this have failed in the last six weeks?" then the answer is "Yes", it sounds like that is exactly what happened.

There is a train of thought that both calipers have done the exact same amount of service and if one was replaced it would be logical that the other would need replacement soon.  Replacing calipers are a precautionary measure however, is an expensive business as it's hard to say for certain when they will fail.

If you are replacing the caliper you can not do with without opening up the hydraulics for the braking system so part of the job will be to flush (or bleed) the system otherwise air may become trapped and you'll get a spongy brake pedal or even brake failure.  I'm unsure why you're asking if it's reasonable to pay for this work again as it is part of the job in replacement of the leaking caliper.